# How to setup clustering in Postgresql?

Tags: cluster-computing, postgresql-9.1, database-replication

Do I have to setup replication to have clustering setup in PostgreSQL? Can I not have just clustering setup in two servers.

PostgreSQL 9.1
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Why are you using an outdated and un-maintained version? To setup replication see the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/high-availability.html

Comment: I have my current production server with this version and anyways, I'm not too specific with version what I exactly want is how to build a high available clustering solution with pgpool-2 on ubuntu platform ?